# Is modulo faster than equality test?

Tags: c, performance, loops, if-statement, modulo

My program is iterating through a list starting from an arbitrary index and wrapping around. Which of these two would be most performant approach  ?

```c
void example(int list[], unsigned int length, unsigned int start) {
  unsigned int i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i ++) {
    printf("%d\n", list[(start + i) % length]);
  }
```

or

```c
void example(int list[], unsigned int length, unsigned int start) {
  unsigned int i;
  i = start;
  do {
    printf("%d\n", list[i]);
    i += 1;
    if (i == length) i = 0;
  } while (i != start); /* fails the first time because i increments before the check */
}
```

Comment: A very easy way to find out is to test it

Comment: The answer is likely to depend on what hardware you're running on, so if you know which CPU your program will be used on, you should come up with a performance test and measure it both ways on that CPU.  (That said, when I had a similar question about code running on my 2018 Intel Mac Mini, I found that modulo was slower)

Comment: @klutt has a great answer. "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil". The `printf("%d")` will dwarf your loop logic.

Comment: @ ice-wind If the body of the loop actually has a `printf`, then optimizing the loop logic is pointless. If the body of the loop doesn't contain a `printf`, then that should be stated in the question (and an estimate of the number of lines of code in the loop body should be given).

Comment: The absent validation of `start` means the 2nd version is open to bad memory access from bad parameters... The modulo version prevents that possibility.

Comment: @ice-wind.  Note that the functions do **not** have the same functionality for all `length, start`.  An incorrect functionality is not useful - even if faster.  Better to first get the functionality correct, then worry about performance.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest would most likely be something like this:

```
for(i=start; i<length; i++) {
    ...
}

for(i=0; i<start; i++) {
    ...
}
```

But also, the call to `printf` might be the issue, so one thing that might speed things up is to build a buffer and then print it all at once.

However, before doing anything of that, make sure that this actually is a bottleneck.

Comment: Corner: To handle [@Fe2O3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76025171/is-modulo-faster-than-equality-test#comment134083330_76025171) concern about using an _arbitrary index_ for `start`, a prior `length == 0` test and `start %= length` are warranted.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica True, but I think that would only bloat the answer

Comment: Well... The question was `Which of these two... ?` :)